# How to execute a test record (one row) of excel sheet without getting the test record failed in selenium(testng)

Tags: excel, selenium, automated-tests, testng

I have an application in which i want to login .The login will be successful (providing correct user id and password)and the page will redirect to home page only on successful login .
However on login failure the page wont redirect to another page it will simply say "please enter correct details"

i have a excel sheet with correct user id and password and also with incorrect user id and password .

Consider below sequence:

1. Correct user id and password
2. Correct user id and password
3. Incorrect user id and password
4. correct user id and password
5. ..... correct user id and password
   .
   .
   .
   50... Correct user id and password

Now if i execute my program using excel sheet ,the program works fine for test records 1 2 , how ever since test record 3 is not correct detail so program stops execution and all rest 3 to 50 test record does not get evaluated.

What i want is some mechanism that if the user id and password is incorrect the test record shall pass(indicating TRUE NEGATIVE) . Can assertion do so?

Comment: Provide the code snippets that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `TestNG` library for that, where the xml file contains the suites, it executes the test case order as you mention in the file see below it will executes "FirstTestCase" then "SecondTestCase" likewise..
So you can do one thing maintain an one file call `testng.xml` which contains suites like this..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="testng" preserve-order="true">

    <test name="FisrtTestCase_001">
        <parameter name="test-id" value="firsttestcase_001"/>
        <parameter name="test-config" value="LotEntryConfig"/>
        <parameter name="test-config-sheet" value="LotAdd"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="testDrivers.TestDriver"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="SecondTestCase_002">
        <parameter name="test-id" value="secondtestcase_002"/>
        <parameter name="test-config" value="FarmerRegConfig"/>
        <parameter name="test-config-sheet" value="NewReg"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="testDrivers.TestDriver"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

 </suite> <!-- testng-->
```

Like wise you can insert the more suites so the advantage is that if any of the test case fails then the execution won't stop, but you need to developed that logic like in my case i have get three parameters `test-id, config-file, sheet-name`

so that the test case executes in such a way that the the whatever the config file is present or not if present then the sheet name is present or not, if present then the test-id is present in the column or not, if present then fetch the all value from that row and store it into an array so you wisely whenever i want..

i have shared the link with you for reference..

https://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html

https://www.toolsqa.com/testng-tutorial/

Hope you understand it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code in `try-catch` block in order to avoid program termination. I am assuming you might have following code structure in your code:

```
@Test
public void validateCredentials(String username, String password)
{
 //do login and check for credentials
 for (int i=0; i<array.lenth; i++)
 {
   try{
   if(successful go ahead){}
   else
     throw new Exception("Not valid credentials")
   } catch(Exception e){ e.printstacktrace();}
 }
}
```

In this case, let's say at number 3, you have invalid credentials, it will throw the exception and in `catch` block it will be handled and it won't stop your code in between in case failure happens.